# video is not working in chrome, just in different browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am currently working on a website, and I just realize the background video only works in safari and Mozilla, it doesn't work in chrome.

different things

```
<div class="container">
    <video width="640" height="360"  style="width:100%;" loop muted>
                <source src="/assets/vdc-video.MP4" type="video/MP4"     style="width:100%;"/>
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
        </div>
```

be able to autoplay video in both navigation tools.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

add controls and autoplay to the video tag

```
<video width="" height="" controls autoplay>
...
</video>
```

Comment: If I add autoplay the video duplicates, I don't understand why.